# Is there some functions like zip and fold in Perl?

Tags: perl, dictionary, zip, fold

I want to use some function such as ["zip"](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zip_f.html), ["fold"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) and ["map"](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/map_f.html) in perl. (Just like in Haskell.) I found map and it works well. Then, is there zip and fold?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Another module you might find interesting is [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Loops).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've implemented many of those functions (and even Haskell-like lazy ones) in my module [List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen)

```
use List::Gen qw(zip reduce);

my @list = zip [1 .. 4], ['a' .. 'd'];

my $str = reduce {$a . $b} @list;

say $str; # 1a2b3c4d
```

Or using the `glob` function to build the ranges:

```
use List::Gen 'glob';

say <1 .. 4>->zip(<a .. d>)->reduce('$a.$b'); # 1a2b3c4d
```

Using `->reduce('.')` or `->reduce(sub {$a . $b})` also works.

Or if you are golfing:

```
say <[.]>->(<1..4>|<a..d>);
```

Or for the Haskell versions, see [List::Gen::Haskell](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen%3a%3aHaskell)

Answer (score 10):

The [`List::Util`](http://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) library includes `reduce()`, which does essentially what `fold` does.

[`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) contains a `zip()` function.

Neither is built-in, mostly because Perl is not a functional programming language.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Wooble! They are all I need!

Comment: @madper: Be aware that Perl has built-in [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) (filter).

Comment: `reduce` isn't builtin, but it is part of the core Perl.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in using functional programming concepts in Perl, then I highly recommend that you read [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Modules that provide functional programming tools:

- Perl's [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)
- [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil)
- [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)
- [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) and [List::Gen::Haskell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen%3a%3aHaskell) (including lazy lists)
- [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aLoops)

You might also be interested in the (now free to download) book [Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/).